# Jmeter: Regular expression to extract code like \"CODE\":\"12345\"

Tags: jmeter

Please guide how to extract below 'CODE' data in Jmeter using Reg expression or any other option. I have tried (.\d+) (.+?)* but it says as Match count: 0

in my reqest's response getting data as:

```
{"d":["[{\"RowNo\":321,\"CODE\":\"12345\",\"T_CODE\":\"TS8\"
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `\` characters and you good to go with [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor):

```
 Regular expression: CODE\\":\\"(\w+)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Able to retrieve the data successfully now.